# Sum of $\sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty {\frac{{m(m + 1)}}{2}} {p^{\frac{{m(m - 1)}}{2}}}\left( {1 - {p^m}} \right)$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation

I'm trying to find if the following sum is converging to some known identity:

$$\sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{m(m + 1)}}{2}} {p^{\frac{{m(m - 1)}}{2}}}\left( {1 - {p^m}} \right)$$

$$ p \in [{0,1}] $$

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hint:  Note that $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}+ m$.

Comment: @Doc I think you can freely submit your answer, because the person who asked the question was not seen at MSE after that day.

Answer (score 1):

I am suggested to think that the answer is negative, because series of the form $\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m p^{m^2}$ are not natural in the analysis, in contrast to series of the form $\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m p^m$.

Comment: Alex, the answer can't be negative.  Each individual summand is nonnegative.

Comment: oops .. totally misinterpreted what you meant by negative in your statement.  Got it now though.  Sorry!

Comment: On second thought ... I retract my earlier comment.  At first glance. I misread the problem.  I saw the term $1-p^m$ as $(1-p)^m$.  That is where my earlier hint (that ${m+1\choose 2}={m\choose 2} + m$) had more relevance.  In that case one could interpret each term as relating to a probability.  I think the problem is intriguing, and it's a shame that the person who asked it has never returned to MSE.